# wget - 401 Unauthorized, but URL is working fine

Tags: wget, unauthorized

Below is the command I'm trying.

```
wget -o /tmp/response.txt <url> --ca-certificate=< my-ca-cert> --certificate=< my-cert> --private-key=< my-private-key> --no-check-certificate
```

**Result:**

HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 401 Unauthorized

Authorization failed.

Note: I've checked for the ceritificates, private keys, etc and those are good. Also, when I'm trying to hit the URL directly from browser, it is working fine.

Please suggest.

Comment: Guys, any thoughts on the above?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After almost an year, I got the solution for my issue.

Since the URL was working in a browser, I went ahead and inspected through WireShark and found out that, this URL was internally connecting to a *SiteMinder*
for `Authentication`.

I had to allow the linux box (used for `wget` command) in the SiteMinder and it worked like a charm!

Comment: Hi, could you share an example about how to allow the linux box in the SiteMinder?